# Remove a field from an object using Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to send a data attribute to an API server only if the method is `add`, if it's `delete`, I don't don't want to send my data.

I have

```
var body =
{
    id: 1,
    method: method,
    params: [
        {
            data: {
                "key1" : "value1",
                "key2" : "value2",
                "key3" : "value3"
            },

            url: `/url/anything`
        }
    ],
    session: session,
    verbose: 1
};
```

I tried

```
if(method == 'delete') {
    _.pick(body.params[0], ['data']);
}
```

I also tried

```
if(method == 'delete') {
    _.pick(body.params[0],'data');
}
```

For some reason, I still see that I still sending the `data`.

How would one go about debugging this?

Comment: Use `===` not `==` ... doesn't solve your issue, but it's best practice

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 1):

if you take a look at [lodash pick documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#pick) you'll see that it doesn't change the source object instead its create a new object from the source object  properties and returns the new object , if you want to remove the **data** property from the source object  , you can use the [unset method from lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#unset) which removes a property from an object or a set of  props ,
also you can use the [delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

Answer (score 1):

use `_.assign`:

```
var body =
{
    id: 1,
    method,
    params: [
        _.assign({url: `/url/anything`}, method === 'delete'
            ? null
            : {
                  data: {
                      "key1" : "value1",
                      "key2" : "value2",
                      "key3" : "value3"
                  }
              }
        ) 
    ],
    session,
    verbose: 1
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do this.

```
if(method === 'delete') {
    body.params[0].data = undefined;
}
```

In this case, we delete all of the content of `data` by assign `undefined`.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.